# Cannot chroot bash after setting RUNPATH in ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with patchelf 0.6 and 0.8

Tags: dynamic-linking, ld, patchelf

I am testing how dynamic linking works with `RUNPATH` variable, and trying to run `bash` in a minimal `chroot` directory:

```
$ find dir_chroot/ -type f
dir_chroot/bin/bash
dir_chroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
dir_chroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
dir_chroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
dir_chroot/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

-- these are all dependencies of `bash`, and they are actual binaries (`find -type f`), not symbolic links.
Also they don't have `RUNPATH`:

```
$ find dir_chroot/ -type f -exec sh -c "readelf -d {} | grep RUNPATH" \;
$
```

`chroot` works fine with this directory:

```
$ sudo chroot dir_chroot /bin/bash
bash-4.3# exit
exit
```

However, if I copy everything and set `RUNPATH` to `$ORIGIN/` in `lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` I get exit code `139` (`segfault`?) when running `chroot`:

```
$ cp -R dir_chroot dir_chroot4
$ find dir_chroot4/ -type f -exec sh -c "echo {} `readelf -d {} | grep RUNPATH`" \; 
dir_chroot4/bin/bash
dir_chroot4/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
dir_chroot4/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
dir_chroot4/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
dir_chroot4/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
$
$ patchelf --set-rpath "\$ORIGIN/" dir_chroot4/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
$ find dir_chroot4/ -type f -exec sh -c "echo {} `readelf -d {} | grep RUNPATH`" \; 
dir_chroot4/bin/bash
dir_chroot4/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
dir_chroot4/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
dir_chroot4/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
dir_chroot4/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH) Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/]
$
$ sudo chroot dir_chroot4 /bin/bash
$
$ echo $status
139
```

-- `$status` is the status variable in `fish` shell.

It happens only if `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is patched, other libraries and `bash` executable work ok with `RUNPATH`. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, *ld-linux-x86-64.so.2* is statically linked, at least it is on my system:

```
>ldd ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
statically linked
```

unlike *libc.so.6*,*libdl.so.2* and *libtinfo.so.5*

```
>ldd libc.so.6 libdl.so.2 libtinfo.so.5

libc.so.6:
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056469847a000)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe95185000)

libdl.so.2:
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc4718000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa1df136000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558334a9c000)

libtinfo.so.5:
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe1b7bd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffa990b9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005590bfced000)
```

which makes the loader go mad and results in a segfault, when you forcibly inject *RUNPATH* into it.

Comment: yep, apparently it is so. If you know how to link a shared/dynamic library statically, could you add it to the answer for testing purposes? When I statically link an executable it doesn't have a dynamic section -- nowhere to add a `RUNPATH`. Also [this test on github](https://github.com/calebmadrigal/static-shared-lib.git) doesn't work for me, breaks with: `relocation R_X86_64_32 against __TMC_END__ can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Comment: > If you know how to link a shared/dynamic library statically, could you add it to the answer for testing purposes?

Well, not sure I will be able to help you with this. You can probably give a try to some tool like Statifier http://statifier.sourceforge.net/, but AFAIK they all are rather hackish and can break things.

So, I would probably just recompile the library in question from sources instead.

BTW I guess this would make a nice question on its own !